# Index creation through telegraf

Tags: elasticsearch, telegraf

Using telegraf i'm able to see system metric in grafana but i have requirement in which i need to create an index of application log, so my questions are :

1) Can telegraf send application log (in csv format) to influxdb

2) Can telegraf create an index in elasticsearch?

Comment: why do you mix these two totally different things together? could you please elaborate on that? what's you're final goal, basically - you want to have _what_ (or, in other words, what you need this index for)?

Comment: See if https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/exec and https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/elasticsearch can help you. Creating index may be the end tool feature (like Splunk does it for free if you feed data to it).